# How use pandas concat in loop to merge large numbers of subCSVs

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to merge large numbers of subCSVs to one CSV.

And I want them merged in row alignment.

I have tried `pd.concat([df1, df4], axis=1)`

But the result CSV's data is the last subCSV's data.  It's not merged.

What I want:

```
A     B        AB
A  +  B   ->   AB
A     B        AB
```

Here is the code:

```
def listdirInMac(path):
    os_list = os.listdir(path)
    for item in os_list:
        if item.startswith('.') and os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, item)):
            os_list.remove(item)
    os_list.sort()
    return os_list

root='/Users/alex/Documents/data/want/test/'
result=pd.DataFrame()
pieces=[]
#all txt data will append on this variable
for file in listdirInMac(root):
    if 'CSV' in file:          
        pathname=os.path.join(root,file)  #file path 
        #print pathname
        temp=pd.read_csv(pathname,usecols=[1],header=None)  # read csv
        result = pd.concat([newfile,temp],axis=1)

result.to_csv('/Users/alex/Documents/data/1/result.csv')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend reading your dataframes in the loop, and calling `pd.concat` *just once* outside.

```
pieces = []
for file in listdirInMac(root):
    ...
    pieces.append(temp)
```

Now that you have your list of DataFrames, just pass that to `concat`:

```
df = pd.concat(pieces, axis=1)
df.to_csv(...)
```